# Struts2: How do i get ServletRequest instance in ActionSupport

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, struts2

How do I get the `ServletRequest` instance in my action?

I implemented `ServletRequestAware` but I am not able to get request object in the action.

struts.xml

```xml
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">
    <action name="Cart"
    class="struts.cart.action.CartAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result type="json"/> 
    </action>   
</package>
```

I am making call using Ajax/JavaScript:

```js
req.onreadystatechange = onReadyState;  
req.open(POST, Cart.action, false);  
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");  
req.send(JSONstr);
```

JSON object:

```js
var data = { cartItem: {
     modelNo: $('#modelNo').val(),
     description: $('#description').val(),
     price: $('#price').val(),
     action: $('#action').val(),
     quantity: $('#quantity').val()
}};
JSONstr = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Action:

```java
public class CartAction extends ActionSupport implements  ServletRequestAware {

    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private Map cartItem = new HashMap();

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("request  " + cartItem); // getting here cartitem
        System.out.println("request  " + request);  // request  null 
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        this.request = httpServletRequest;
    }

    public Map getCartItem() {
        return cartItem;
    }

    public void setCartItem(Map cartItem) {
        this.cartItem = cartItem;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest() ;
```

Comment: While this works, implementing `ServletRequestAware` is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

1. Why do you *need* the servlet request? It's rare it's required.
2. The reason ServletRequestAware isn't working is because you removed the interceptor that sets it into the action:

```xml
<action name="Cart" class="struts.cart.action.CartAction">
  <interceptor-ref name="json">
    <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <result type="json"/> 
</action>
```

When you set *any* interceptors in an action's configuration you must set *all* interceptors.

Here you've *removed* all the default interceptors, including "servletConfig" which sets the request for `ServletRequestAware` actions, and are running *only* the `json` interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AjaxActionSupport instead ActionSupport in this way..

```
public class TestAjaxAction extends AJAXActionSupport {
```

//inside this you have perform method where you can get easily both object.

> public void perform(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
>   response) throws AJAXActionException {

Comment: `AJAXActionSupport` doesn't belong to S2 core. At least give a FQN.